cPanel/WHM exim Advanced Editor duplicating rather than replacing config section
I need to add a configuration line to the remote_smtp & dkim_remote_smtp sections of our exim configuration to deal with an ongoing problem with Yahoo email. When I open the exim Advanced Editor, copy the TRANSPORTMIDDLE current configuration text into the text box labeled "Section TRANSPORTMIDDLE:", add my one line to each section and save it, the update fails because the "mailman_virtual_transport" section is duplicated in the output because my modified version has been added to the configuration instead of replacing the existing section. I saw this problem was asked 8 years ago (https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/92682/whms-exim-advanced-editor-not-accepting-settings-for-dkim), but that question was closed with a referral to a different forum. I have not found any answer to the correct way to modify the TRANSPORTMIDDLE section of the configuration. Our hosting provider is no help and the WHM to cPanel ticket mechanism isn't working. What am I missing? Help!
